# Interface with defined number of members

Tags: typescript

I need to write an interface which has only two members of undefined name and one of them is optional. Something like

```
interface MyInterface {
    [required: string]: string|number
    [optional: string]?: string|number
}
```

Of course this doesn't work because indexed types allow an undefined number of properties and it will cause a `Duplicate index signature for type 'string'` error but i think it explains well what i need to do. I didn't find any way to achieve this yet, if it is possible.

##### Use case

This is a DynamoDB context.
We have an item which can be of two different types: one that has only a primary key which is a unique identifier and another that has got a pair of keys, primary and secondary, which together make a unique identifier.

```
// Input with a single primary key only
User = {
    email: "user@email", // this is the primary key
    ... 
}

// Item with primary and secondary keys
Post = {
    title: "Post Title", // this is the primary key
    author: "user@email", // this is the secondary key
    ...
}
```

To access the first item we use:

```
get({ email: "user@email" }) {
    // make something with this input
}
```

For the second item, we use:

```
get({ title: "Post Title", author: "user@email" }) {
    // make something whit this other input
}
```

We need `get()` to accept both, but we don't know what the primary or secondary keys are called.

##### My actual implementation

At the moment `get()` takes this type of input

```
interface Input {
    PrimaryKey: string|number
    SecondaryKey?: string|number
}

get({ PrimaryKey: "user@email" }: Input) {
    // Retrieves the key name by querying the table.
}

get({ PrimaryKey: "Post title", SecondaryKey: "user@email" }: Input) {
    // Retrieves the pair names by querying the table.
}
```

This works, but using `PrimaryKey` and `SecondaryKey` instead of their actual names can easily get confusing.

Comment: How would you declare what key is required and what key os optional? Please provide some example that show how you think you would declare and use objects of this type. Does something like this meet your needs? https://tsplay.dev/wQVa1N

Comment: What is the use case?

Comment: There's no specific type which behaves like that; you could spend a lot of effort writing a generic type that could be used to "check" if a value looks like that.  But even so, the language doesn't really prohibit extra properties.  Trying to do this would be an exercise in fighting against the type system.  Maybe you could explain your use case?  It would probably be better to refactor your code to something that doesn't depend on number of properties, but it's hard to know what that is without more info.

Comment: I've added some info about the use case in the question!

Answer (score 0):

It sound atypical to me that Typescript would keep track of the number of properties. Maybe you could use a tuple instead? Something like this.

```js
interface A {
  key: string,
  value: string | number
}
type B = [A] | [A, A]
```

And with a helper function for property access.

```js
const get = (b: B, key: string): string | number | undefined =>
  b.find((item) => item.key === key)?.value
```